# Having trouble creating a sticky navigation bar at the very bottom of the responsive website

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, sticky

I created a navigation bar below the image to display icons for various social media platforms. However, I am trying to place these icons at the very bottom of the website and make it responsive depending on the size of the screen (PC & mobile).

I have tried placing the position: 'sticky' from 'absolute' and placed the 'index = -999', but it doesn't seem to be working fine.

This is what I have:

[image]

HTML

```
 <div class ="bottom">
        <div class = "logos">
            <a href="https://github.com/j-ahn94" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github"></a>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/14266888/jason-a" target="_blank" class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonja-ahn/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/*Adding body and * as it might be relevant to my problem*/

body {
    background-color: black; /*rgb(241, 233, 233);*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logos {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
}

.logos a {
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: is this the only thing that your page has? Is there any content after the image and the navigation bar?

Comment: Hello. There is a navigation bar at the top where it provides 'Home', 'About', etc. I cut it out since I thought it was not necessary to this concern.

Comment: The top navigation is good information but i really want to know if there is going to be any other content after the image and the navigation bar with the icons

Comment: As for this front page of the website, there won't be any content after the image and the navbar with the icons. Thank you for the help..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your body is missing the height attribute. It does not reach the bottom, so you will have to give it a height. The vh should do the trick. (100vh). This meaning that your document will always have at least the height of the device that it is accessing it.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: black; /*rgb(241, 233, 233);*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.bottom {
   margin-top: auto;
}
.logos {
  display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
.logos a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class = "logos">
        <a href="https://github.com/j-ahn94" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github">Text 1</a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/14266888/jason-a" target="_blank" class="fa fa-stack-overflow">Text 2</a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonja-ahn/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin">Text 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your sticky element top property to be calc 100vh (screen size) and the height of your element (for example 85px), like this:

```
.logos {
    top: calc(100vh - 85px);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).